# Reading shared variable from another thread (Effective Java #66)

Tags: java, concurrency

In *Effective Java*: item 66, Joshua Bloch gave an example about life failure:

```
// Broken! - How long would you expect this program to run
class StopThread {
    private static boolean stopRequested = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws InterruptedException {

        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while (!stopRequested) {
                    i++;
                }
           }
        });
        backgroundThread.start();

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        stopRequested = true;
    }   
}
```

As Joshua Bloch said, this program would not terminate.
But, if I change `i++` into `System.out.println(i++)`, it terminates successfully!

I can't figure out how it happens!

Comment: Independent of the answers, you also need to consider that the book is 10 years and 3 major versions old. Things change, sometimes.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Sometimes they don't, though: the behaviour reported in the item still happens.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know. Which is why I provided this as comment, not as answer

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd What you said is a red herring. What held true for Java 10 years ago is still largely true today. In this particular case, the concurrency behavior is still totally legal and according to spec.

Comment: I never said otherwise. I am a huge advocate of Effective Java myself.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is related to the memory value of the variable `stopRequest`.

This variable is **not defined as `volatile`**.

If you have a two processors the inner thread check the value of `stopRequest` taken from its registry.

The main thread alter the value of `stopRequest` in the registry of the other processor.

So the main thread modify a value of `stopRequest` but the thread see only a copy of it that never changes.

*Modified after take a look at the source code of `PrintStream` (thanks to the commend of ΔλЛ)*: Using a `System.out.print` command will use an explicit `synchronized` block to print the value passed to it this will grant that the value of `stopRequest` is taken from the main memory and not from the registry of the processor.

Adding a `volatile` keyword will inform the JVM to take the value from the main memory instead from the registries of the processors and it solve the problem.

Also using the keyword `synchronized` will solve this problem because any variable used in the synchronized block is taken and update the main memory.

Memory model without `volatile` (Main thread use Processor 1 and explicit thread use Processor 2)

```
Processor 1         Processor 2     Main memory
-----------         -----------     -----------
  false                false           false
  true                 false           true       // After setting 
                                                  //stopRequest to true
```

Defining `stopRequest` as `volatile` where all threads read `stopRequest` from main memory.

```
    Processor 1         Processor 2     Main memory
-----------         -----------     -----------
       NA                   NA           false
       NA                   NA           true       // After setting 
                                                  //stopRequest to true
```

Comment: @flkes: it would be better to use interruption for this, and not make a flag that duplicates existing functionality. should mention that the println acquires a lock and it ends up forcing the variable's updated value to become visible.

Comment: Yes.... but I think that the efforts of Joshua were to explain that also a subtle error can create very strange errors, but for sure also an AtomicBoolean will solve this problem.

Comment: @NathanHughes true; could just call `Thread::interrupt`. I was just thinking more generally about accessing a boolean from multiple threads.

Comment: I think it's important to note that just adding `synchronized` isn't guaranteed to solve the problem, unless both threads synchronize on the same exact object. Otherwise, the synchronization makes it a bit more likely that the write will be see, but not guaranteed.

Comment: @ ΔλЛ You are true. It is not a new thread. Just the synchronized keyword that will cause the read from the main memory. Thanks

Comment: @yshavit's comment is correct. Just using `synchronized` is not enough; both threads have to perform `synchornized` on the same object to guarantee that the new value is passed from one thread to the other.

Comment: @Nayuku and Yshavid is not true. Calling synchronized also with different monitors will work. What happens when is used a synchronized block is that all variables used in that block are read and written to/from the main memory. Synchronizing on the same monitor guarantees that only one thread per time will enter it. But this is not a problem related to the synchronization, but to the value not propagated to all threads. Defining it as volatile or accessing it from a synchronized block is enough also if the other thread synchronize on a different monitor.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO No, that's not true. In order for there to not be a data race, there has to be a happens-before relationship between the writing thread and the reading thread. One way to do that is for the writer to release a monitor before the reader acquires that _same_ monitor. Note [JLS 17.4.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4): "An unlock action on monitor m synchronizes-with all subsequent lock actions **on m**" (emphasis added)

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO thank you very much. I checked the source code of PrintStream, and found this line: `println(int x) { synchronized (this) { ... } }`. When `print i`, `stopRequest` thread hold the lock of the object, and `stopRequested` also stored in that object, so this time `stopRequest` thread just read it directly. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: It's most likely an "accidental" side effect of `println` being synchronized.

First, realize that it's not the case that the thread is *guaranteed not* to finish; it's that it's not guaranteed that it *will* finish. In other words, the race condition on `stopRequested` — caused by the fact that one thread is writing to it, and another thread is reading from it, and there's no synchronization between the two threads — means that the JVM *may*, but is not required to, let the reader see what the writer has done.

So, why does `System.out.println` change this? Because it's a synchronized method. This doesn't actually give you any guarantees about `stopRequested` as far as the JLS is concerned, but it does mean that the JVM has to do some things, like acquiring a(n unrelated) lock, and establishing (unrelated) happens-before edges, that make it more likely that the write to `stopRequested` will be seen across threads.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not telling the thread that `stopRequested` is a value that can be modified from outside that thread there are no guarantees that the `while` will evaluate to the most recent value of the variable.

This is why the `volatile` keyword is useful in this situation, because it will explicitly enforce that `stopRequested` value, when read, will be the most recent value set by any thread.

There are further considerations, actually from the point of view of the thread, `stopRequested` is a loop invariant, since it is never set by only read, so optimization choices should be considered too: if a value is thought not to be modified then there is no reason to evaluate it on each iteration.

Comment: It doesn't explain the effect of `System.out.println()` in this context though.

Comment: The effect of `System.out.println()` is not certain IMHO, on some machine it could solve the problem on some others it couldn't so it's irrelevant to understand the reason since the problem is elsewhere. According to how threads are allocated on CPUs, who is taking care of buffered output and such things. It's a sort of undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jack my question is: why `System.out.println()` changes the state of program, even not using `synchronized` and `volatile` key words.

Comment: @HuangDong.Li: that's an XY problem, it's irrelevant why something __seems__ to fix a problem when the problem is elsewhere. It's like asking why checking for `var != nullptr` when `var` is unitialized in C++ works when compiled without optimization under a specific environment. Totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` requests a resource to write on the console, which in itself a blocking method… meaning, it will block the `backgroundThread()` to `print()` on the console. This is similar to sending an interrupt to it.

Thus, `backgroundThread()` will become aware of the change in the value of the boolean and stop executing, thereby terminating the Daemon.